# What's the right way to perform incremental "all-or-nothing" imports in sqoop?

Tags: sqoop

According to the [Sqoop user guide](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.5/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_export_literal), in order to perform an "all-or-nothing" load into a RDMS, a staging table can be used.

However, this option only seems to be available in exports. When performing an import (from SQLServer) into HDFS, the option --staging-table is not present. By default, Sqoop imports use the read committed transaction isolation policy. What if one of the import mappers fail? If the import I'm performing is an incremental one, will sqoop perform a "rollback" of the whole operation, so that no data are imported?

We have implemented a workflow which performs an incremental import from an SQL table over a temporary HDFS directory and then, if everything goes right, performs a merge over the "main" HDFS table, with all the data from previous imports. This is basically a handmade staging table for imports. Is this the right/efficient way to proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the sqoop `import` fails, for example if one of the mappers hadoop's `max.retries` number of times and still fails, the whole sqoop import will fail with an error.  I suspect that the table being written to (in HDFS) will be incomplete and probably needs to be deleted, but you'll know from the error, right?

`export` and `import` are near opposites of each other -- import copies data from the source RDBMS and is able to take advantage of sophisticated locking of relations DB to ensure a consistent state of the data as it is read.  HDFS has no such guarantees (as far as I am aware), but at least Sqoop can be sure that what it copied from RDBMS has made it completely to HDFS intact.

But when going the other direction (`export`) all that Sqoop knows is whether its read of HDFS completed without error, but has no concurrency or other such protections of RDBMSs.  Thus the `export` option suggests the staging table as a mechanism for ensuring that all data is successfully in the RDBMS staging location, after which Sqoop can use the RDBMS copy from staging to the final result to ensure consistency, locking, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Tom.
So if one of the mappers fails, and consequently the whole incremental import fails, I cannot assume that no data (from the other successful mappers) will be written to the HDFS table, right? 

If I were doing incremental imports of an SQL table to HDFS for a long period of time and suddenly one mapper of one particular incremental import failed, the way to ensure consistency would be to delete the whole HDFS file?